# What is type "SIMPLE"?

Tags: abap

I have this code:

```
cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create( )->convert(
        EXPORTING
          input = lo_json_writer->get_output( )
        IMPORTING
          data = json ).
```

`JSON` is my variable and I want to choose the matching type for it.

I double-click on the convert method to investigate:

I see in the signature of `convert()` that the export parameter `data` is of the built-in type `SIMPLE`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find canonical documentation from SAP for the type `SIMPLE` with my favorite search engine.

What data type should I use for my variable `JSON`?

Comment: You should check F1 document. https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenbuilt_in_types_generic.htm

Comment: @Haojie yes, you are right. I hope that I will learn to use F1 instead of my favorite search engine in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbuilt_in_types_generic.htm), `SIMPLE` is a generic type which is an

> [Elementary data type](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenelementary_data_type_glosry.htm) including [enumerated types](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenenumerated_type_glosry.htm) and structured types with exclusively character-like flat components

The Elementary Data Types comprise the Predefined Data Types C, X, STRING, XSTRING, D, I, ... plus the Standalone Data Types based on one of these predefined types. The Standalone data types themselves comprise the Bound Data Types (C, N, P and X with any length). Of course, the Data Elements from the ABAP Dictionary are also considered as being Elementary Data Types, except those which are references to other data elements.

Enumerated types and Flat structured types are also considered as Elementary data types.

Thanks Sandra for making this answer much better.

Comment: @Sandra Rossi, thanks for your edits. you can copy the whole answer, as it all yours, and i will delete mine...

Comment: Maybe I did too much [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), although I "just" added the details of what is an elementary data type, to "[Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)". If you feel I changed it too much, then sorry, you can rollback it, and I will add my complement as a comment (anyway stackoverflow encourages to edit the answer "so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place"). What is important finally (to me), is to have a "good answer to a good question".

Comment: @Sandra Rossi, I meant it's wonderful and you deserve the credit. Well done!